# can I use apache beam on aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-beam, aws-glue

I have a beam code that do some etl stuff running on google dataflow (getting files path on gsp from pubsub).

My company in looking to do the switch to aws and That code also need to move (for start only the code will move and then we'll change the pubsub and gsp to aws services). The code would also need to update athena at the end.

Is there any way to use beam in glue (or other service that would do the job)? I know beam and glue both support spark so maybe something with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean whether there's an Apache Beam Runner for AWS Glue ? I don't believe there is one currently.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whats the best managed service in aws that can run streamed beam?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics for Apache Flink](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/what-is.html) and use the managed Flink as the runner for Beam [info here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/)